# Eye blink detection with tracking js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, face-detection, eye-detection

I am looking for pure java script solution for eye blink detection using tracking js or any other js lib. 70 to 80 % accuracy is fine for me.

Using Tracking js, With below code, I can get eye's bounding rectangle.  Any ideas how to achieve blink detection?

```
  var tracker = new tracking.ObjectTracker( 'eye');
  tracker.setStepSize(1.7);

  tracking.track('#img', tracker);

  tracker.on('track', function(event) {
    event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
      // drawing rectangle on canvas
      window.plot(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Why are you tagging opencv if you want pure javascript solution? Opencv has javascript bindings if that's what you need.

Comment: I know there is a open cv js, but don't find any opencvjs tags.